# Make pseudo element's height the same as the element it is attached to

Tags: css, pseudo-element

I have a very quick question but I don't know how to phrase it optimally to get a relevant search result. Basically I have a `<div class="element"></div>` with `.element{height:100px}`. I'm adding a `after` pseudo element to my `.element` with the same height but I'm not sure how to reference the original height in the pseudo one.

Thank you. (I hope what I just said makes sense)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Sounds like you can simply use 100%:

```
.element:after { 
    content: 'your generated content'; 
    display: block; 
    height: 100%; 
}
```

Comment: ohh how silly of me. I forgot `display:block`. Thank you sir.

Comment: BTW, is this because the parent of the pseudo elements is the original element itself? ty.